# Sort rows by date

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, date, rows

I am new to VBA and having an issue with my table. If my table has a header and dates start from column A2, table size is up to R. I need a way to automatically sort rows by date. Table size is constantly growing, so how to expand selection if needed is preferable.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and doing it manually? It will give you the code to start with then.

Comment: I tried to record a macro, but when i change values with lastrow, it creates a bug. could you please resolve bug here and make sorting automatic, with table being opened, for example.

Comment: ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "A2:A" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:Q" & lastrow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
End Sub

Comment: I cant make any sense of your code when you put it into a comment. Please edit your question and put it there instead.

Comment: You could turn your table into an actual table which will expand as you add data.  You can reference the table using `Set MyTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")`.

Comment: should i add it before my script? and why when i change values to lastrow, it bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in an actual table - highlight the data and select **Insert ~ Table** from the toolbar.
Your table should be called **Table1** (you can manually change this).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyTable As ListObject
    Set MyTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    With MyTable
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
            Key:=Range("Table1[MyDateColumn]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal 'Change MyDateColumn to the name of your date column.
            
        With .Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

You don't need to include the [xlPinYin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsortmethod) method